# Artifactory - remote repos permissions

Tags: permissions, maven-2, repository, artifactory

I'm using Artifactory 3.0.3 (open source).

In our company, we have two own repositories and both are on a different machine than Artifactory. Let's call them:

1. OurRepo1 - public, any developer can download artifacts from it
2. OurRepo2 - private, only some developers are allowed to access and download artifacts from it

And here's the thing:

Due to security reasons we want OurRepo2 not to be cached by Artifactory (easy to do), **BUT NOW**, how can I define permissions for this OurRepo2 to be accessible only by some users?

When I'm creating a new permission target I can select only local repos and caches of remote repos (e.g. OurRepo1-cache). But I don't want either of that. I want to limit the very access to the physical OurRepo2.

Is it possible with Artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd use an HTTP proxy like nginx in front of your Artifactory instances, and use rewrite rules to direct traffic to the correct back-end repo. You can then insist on certain auth credentials when trying to access *OurRepo2* whilst leaving *OurRepo1* free of authentication.

I have helped to manage such an "nginx + Artifactory" combination in an organisation with 100+ developers, and it worked very well.